# Making a duplicate prestashop site for development and testing

Tags: prestashop, subdirectory

How exactly I can make duplicate of existing shop on same domain in different subfolder.

Currently is `example.com`. I want to make duplicate in `example.com/test/` for testing purpose. So I've made the folder and copied every file into it.. also I've create new database and export/import database. Then in table `shop_url` I've change `physical_url to /test/.

So now when I go to `example.com/test/` it is loading full site and images but when I click on some product is go into `example.com/product_name` not in `example.com/test/product_name`. Also I've change in .htaccess this line `RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/test/]` from `/` to `/test/`.

What else I need to change? What I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is done good

1) Copy files

2) Copy MySQL database with change shop_url and shop_url_ssl (should be the same as shop_url)

3) Refresh .htaccess file to new url manualy or via SEO/URL Prestashop setting - first disable mod_rewrite and Save then enable mod_rewrite and Save - that will create new .htaccess file automaticly.

You should consider to delete cache folder and recreate it from clean install or purge *cache/smarty/**compile*** folder.

Change also shop_url_ssl (should be the same as shop_url)

Sometimes You need also clean browser cache memory. Bugs are everywhere :) or try other non used browser to open cloned store.